# MVC - Abstracting a conversion from an entity (or model) to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abstraction

my target is to abstract as much as possible, so i thought something generic for converting from a model (entity) to a viewmodel.

I'd like something like this:

```
IEntityToModelMapper mapper;
mapper.Convert<MyModel>().Map<MyViewModel>();
```

or even:

```
 GenericViewModel model = _mapper.Convert<MyModel>();
```

When "GenericViewModel" is a base class of all ViewModel, but in this case i'd have problem with casting objects. Maybe an Interface?

Mine are just attempts. How would you implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to roll your own, or using an existing library?  Automapper has worked well for me: http://automapper.org/

Comment: I thought to use automapper inside concrete classes, but i want to have an abstraction in my controller in order to have a generic pattern for every entity that should be converted to a ViewModel. I hope i was clear in my explanation...

Comment: ViewModels are not like EntityModels that there would be some common properties e.g. Primary key field so you would create a base  model. Making a generic VM would not serve a meaningful purpose IMO.

Comment: Thinking about it generic ViewModel is not the correct approach, but some kind of abstraction with interface. For example i think of Ninject. It has an interface called IKernel and when you want to bind an interface to a concrete class you call something like:    Ikernel kernel; ... kernel.Bind<MyInterface>().To<MyConcrete>();